# NdisFOidRequest causes SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION BSoD in NDIS filter driver

Tags: c, windows, driver, device-driver, ndis

I have a NDIS filter driver. It intercepts the OID path. When calling this driver from user-mode using `DeviceIOControl`, the system crashes with `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION`.

The dump is here:

```
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff8012066346e, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd000f9930c90, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for npf.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  9600.18202.amd64fre.winblue_ltsb.160119-0600

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  AAEON

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  EPIC-BDU7

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  V1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  PB9UAM12

BIOS_DATE:  07/15/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  AAEON

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  EPIC-BDU7

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  V1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x8
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8012066346e

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd000f9930c90

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
ndis!NdisFOidRequest+62
fffff801`2066346e f780780e000000040000 test dword ptr [rax+0E78h],400h

CONTEXT:  ffffd000f9930c90 -- (.cxr 0xffffd000f9930c90)
rax=656c694602150003 rbx=ffffe00097e1e0c0 rcx=ffffe000980f8b00
rdx=ffffe00097e1e0c0 rsi=00000000c0000001 rdi=ffffe000980f8b00
rip=fffff8012066346e rsp=ffffd000f99316c0 rbp=ffffd000f9931891
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000002 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff801223c4d07 r12=ffffe00097c638c8 r13=ffffe00095a2e3e0
r14=ffffe00097e1e000 r15=ffffe00097e1e098
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
ndis!NdisFOidRequest+0x62:
fffff801`2066346e f780780e000000040000 test dword ptr [rax+0E78h],400h ds:002b:656c6946`02150e7b=????????
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 82f

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3d

CPU_STEPPING: 4

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3d,4,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1F'00000000 (cache) 1F'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  EFANetworkRedu

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  AKISN0W-PC

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-18-2016 23:19:14.0141

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801223c2057 to fffff8012066346e

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`f99316c0 fffff801`223c2057 : 00000000`80000004 ffffe000`97c638c0 00000000`80000004 ffffe000`97c638c0 : ndis!NdisFOidRequest+0x62
ffffd000`f9931780 fffff801`4880e9e0 : 00000000`00000001 ffffe000`95a2e3e0 ffffe000`97483ab0 ffffe000`9818a080 : npf!NPF_IoControl+0x50b [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\packet.c @ 1998]
ffffd000`f9931810 fffff801`488b5fa6 : ffffe000`97483a05 ffffd000`f9931b80 ffffe000`95a64780 ffffe000`97483ab0 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x160
ffffd000`f99318e0 fffff801`48881eee : ffffd000`f9931a38 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0xd86
ffffd000`f9931a20 fffff801`48570bb3 : ffffe000`97a7c080 ffffd000`001f0003 00000000`003ae828 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ffffd000`f9931a90 00000000`777b2352 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`003af128 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x777b2352


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  f354ebcbce73c80400d16c63b39be1a5e6cb013a

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  f520e4b6e586b809f1bb5333e4aeed20386b9eef

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  a42ba1f53eaabb205023e38281f0fec5e9957ea0

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
npf!NPF_IoControl+50b [j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\packet.c @ 1998]
fffff801`223c2057 ??              ???

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\packet.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  j:\npcap\packetwin7\npf\npf\packet.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  1998

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
  1994:                     break;
  1995:                 }
  1996:             }
  1997: 
> 1998:             Status = NdisFOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle, &pRequest->Request);
  1999:         }
  2000:         else
  2001:         {
  2002:             //
  2003:             // Release ownership of the Ndis Handle


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  npf!NPF_IoControl+50b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: npf

IMAGE_NAME:  npf.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56eba84d

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffd000f9930c90 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  50b

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_npf!NPF_IoControl

BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_npf!NPF_IoControl

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x3B_npf!NPF_IoControl

TARGET_TIME:  2016-03-18T14:55:45.000Z

OSBUILD:  9600

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

OSEDITION:  Windows 8.1 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-01-20 00:19:09

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160119-0600

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_ltsb

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.3.9600.18202.amd64fre.winblue_ltsb.160119-0600

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 9ca8

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_npf!npf_iocontrol

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {1a9eb099-6ac7-8089-67e0-fac2e851dbd1}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

The faulty source code is here:

https://github.com/nmap/npcap/blob/master/packetWin7/npf/npf/Packet.c

This bug is so werid. It seems not to happen every time. And I encountered this bug before in another function. (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869373/get-system-service-exception-bluescreen-when-starting-wireshark-on-win10-vmware). Then I commented that call to avoid this bug. But it then shows up here:(

Actually I don't know what causes this bug? Thanks!